# How to change the format of specified lines in a RichTextBox

Tags: c#, winforms, controls, string

I have a winforms RichTextBox containing lots of lines of text (eg 2 MB text files), and would like to programmatically change the formatting of specified lines, eg highlighting them.

How can I address the lines, rather than the characters? Is a RichTextBox even the best control for this sort of thing, or is there another alternative? I have tried the Infragistics UltraFormattedTextEditor, but it was at least a couple of orders of magnitude slower to display text, so no good for my longer files.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To access the lines on textbox controls you use the Lines property

richTextBox.Lines

From there you can iterate through the lines and work with the ones you want to change.

Edit: Agreed, I missed the highlight part (+1 for answering your own question).  Including working code:

```
int lineCounter = 0;
foreach(string line in richTextBox1.Lines)
{
   //add conditional statement if not selecting all the lines
   richTextBox.Select(richTextBox.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(lineCounter), line.Length);
   richTextBox.SelectionColor = Color.Red;
   lineCounter++;
}
```

Comment: that gets me the lines; but how can I tell the RichtTextBox to highlight the lines I want, for example? I can only set SelectedText by character number, not by line...?

Answer (score 1):

OK, I'll document the solution I found: using `richTextBox.Lines` to get the lines as Luis says, then

```
richTextBox.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(int line)
richTextBox.Select(int start, int length)
```

to select the relevant lines, then

```
richTextBox.SelectionColor...
richTextBox.SelectionBackground...
```

etc. etc. to format the lines.